# OSError: libcublas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I tried to import cudamat. Then I ran into the error:

```
OSError: libcublas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to locate libcublas

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libcublas.so.5.0
/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libcublas.so.5.0.40
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/libcublas.so
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/libcublas.so.5.5
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/libcublas.so.5.5.22
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/libcublas_device.a
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libcublas.so
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libcublas.so.5.5
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libcublas.so.5.5.22
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libcublas_device.a
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.5.5
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.5.5.22
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas_device.a
```

What can I do? I'm sorry I'm not familiar with ubuntu. Thank you !

## QUESTION CLOSED

## I solved this myself.

first set PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin:$PATH
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then build a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libcublas.so /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libcublas.so.3
```

Comment: You should post this as an answer.  Then we can mark this question as answered.  It's ok to answer your own questions.

Comment: Thanks, I've followed your suggestion.

Comment: You should accept your answer. (+1 for the answer; I just had the same problem because I switched from `bash` to `zsh`)

Answer (score 14):

**I solved this myself.**

first set PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin:$PATH
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then build a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libcublas.so /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libcublas.so.3
```

Answer (score 1):

In a slightly different situation, the same warning may be raised by literally missing lib file, i.e. the `.lib` files are not at `$CUDA/lib64/`. For instance the following code did not show `libcublas.so` in this directory.

```
sudo find / -iname libcublas*
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/doc/man/man7/libcublas.so.7
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/doc/man/man7/libcublas.7
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.7.5
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas_static.a
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs/libcublas.so
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas_device.a
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.7.5.18
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so
```

The [workaround](https://liujingchu.wordpress.com/2016/02/28/the-missing-libcublas-so/) for this case is different but straightforward: just create symlinks in `$CUDA/lib64/` for all the lib files in `$CUDA/targets/x86_64-linux/lib`. An example one-liner is like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/* $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Just linking to your own stuff is [not a good answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). A good answer that involves an off-site resource includes the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and references the following: _What is this thing you're talking about? Where do I install it? How do I install it? How do I use this thing to solve the **exact problem** I have in my question? Are you affiliated with this thing in any way, shape, or form?_ See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022)