# Use CUDA in virtualenv to serve Theano

Tags: python, cuda, virtualenv, theano, lasagne

Lacking root permissions I installed Theano and Lasagne in a python3 virtualenv at Ubuntu 14.04.

Running some code, I get an `ImportError: dnn not available`, which as far as I see results from missing CUDA header, although it is installed at `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cudnn.h`.

Following the [theano documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#using-the-gpu) I set environment variable `CUDA_ROOT=/usr/local/cuda-6.5`, which yields an additional error:

`ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: libcublas.so.6.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Is there any way to include this CUDA library into the virtualenv?

Comment: I worked around the theano.sandbox error following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026127/oserror-libcublas-so-3-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo) instructions. But still the dnn import error.

Comment: The [theano documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/sandbox/cuda/dnn.html) suggests that you also define your CPATH?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but no results so far. I will try to debug dnn_available() function to find out more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer. In addition to environment variables I forgot to configure the `.theanorc` in my home directory like the [theano documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#using-the-gpu) suggested:

```
$ cat /home/user/.theanorc
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu0

[cuda]
root = /usr/local/cuda-6.5
```

Thanks anyway! Learned the lesson to read docs carefully ...