# libcublas.so cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in ipython and notebook

Tags: ipython, theano, jupyter-notebook

The missing `libcublas.so` problem has been around for some time. The most common problem is that the `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is not set properly. And solutions for command line scenarios have been posted in the [NVIDIA forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/845363/libcublas-so-7-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026127/oserror-libcublas-so-3-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo).

But no specific solution has been out for similar symptoms in ipython or notebook. Here is my own work around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is still due to environment variables: ipython and notebook cannot propagate the settled `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So when this happens, the first thing to check is

```
import os; print(os.environ['PATH']); print(os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'])
```

Most probably the `bin` and `lib` paths are not in these environs.

To solve this for ipython, use `sudo PATH=$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ipython` when starting ipython.

And for notebook, add these lines to the end of `jupyter_notebook_config.py`:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ':/usr/local/cuda/bin'
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64'
```